# If Statement in R involving a date

Tags: r

I need to create an additional column in my dataset which displays a '1' if a column (V1) in a given row displays a date before 25.07.17, and a '2' if the same column (V1) displays a date after 25.07.17.

The code below has created a column, 'Dataset' as I wish, but every single row is a '2' - even the rows for which V1 is after 25.07.17.

```
#add column to identify dataset
if(CombineddatainprogresscsvClean$V1<25.07.17 10:00){
  CombineddatainprogresscsvClean$Dataset=1
}else
{
    CombineddatainprogresscsvClean$Dataset=2
}
```

Can you please tell me where I am going wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If time (hour) should also be taken into condition, you should use:

```
CombineddatainprogresscsvClean$Dataset <- ifelse(as.POSIXct(CombineddatainprogresscsvClean$V1,format = '%d.%m.%y %H:%M') < as.POSIXct('25.07.17 10:00', format = '%d.%m.%y %H:%M'), 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
CombineddatainprogresscsvClean$Dataset <- ifelse(CombineddatainprogresscsvClean$V1 < as.Date("25.07.17", format = "%d.%m.%y"), 1, 2)
```

In order for this to work you have to convert `CombineddatainprogresscsvClean$V1`to date format as well.

Comment: Ok, how do I check what format it is presently in and how do I change that the data format, please? Thank you.

Comment: you can write `class(CombineddatainprogresscsvClean$V1)` to check for the class.
To convert to date see `?as.Date`.
If the date is in the fomat "dd.mm.yy" you can use `as.Date(CombineddatainprogresscsvClean$V1, format = "%d.%m.%y")`